# pieslice() function in C

Tags: c, graphics, geometric-arc, turbo-c, sector

How can I draw a major pieslice in C, using the function `pieslice()`?

```
pieslice(X-centre,Y-centre,StrtAngle,EndAngle,Radius).
```

I am trying to draw a major sector or pieslice in C, using the `pieslice` function; I want the start angle to be 135 degrees and end angle to be 235 degrees, but at the same time it should be the major sector, not the minor sector.

I tried all the four combinations

```
pieslice(100,100,135,-135,20)
pieslice(200,200,225,135,30)
pieslice(300,300,225,360+135,30)
pieslice(400,400,135,225,20)

pieslice(50,50,0,135,30);
pieslice(50,50,225,0,30);
```

But all of them draw the corresponding minor sector not the major sector. Can someone please advise me how to do that?

Here is a screenshot of the output:

[image]

---

Thanks for your effort and time.

Now, I could not make the pieslice to work my way.  However with the following tweak, I am able to get around the problem and get the desired output. I wrote a user defined function `slice(int x-centre, int y-centre,int sangle, int eangle, int radius)` similar to pieslice.
I hope it is useful for those who get stuck in a similar kind of situation:

```
void slice(int x, int y, int sangle, int eangle, int rad)
{
 int i,j,color;
 if(sangle>eangle){
  color=getcolor();
  setcolor(getcolor()) ;
  setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL,color);
  circle(x,y,rad);
  floodfill(x,y,color);
  setcolor(getbkcolor());
  setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL,getbkcolor());
  pieslice(x,y,eangle,sangle,rad);
  setcolor(color);
 }
}
```

Comment: @Timothy: What graphics library are you using? Borland? What error messages do you see? Can you show us how you are actually calling the function in your code? (Also: the second call to `pieslice` has a typo.)

Comment: @Dave i am using turboc graphics library on windows platform

Comment: @dave yeah tht was a typing mistake ;

Comment: @thrustmaster : i am using turboc graphics library on windows platform.

Comment: @Timothy: It has been over a decade, but I think if you hit CTRL-F1 with the cursor on the `pieslice` function, it will display a help screen showing how to call it.

Comment: this is the sample code, however there are no errors, only thing is that i m getting minor slice instead of major slice
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<graphics.h>
void main()
{
 int maxx,minx,bl_div,len;
 int maxval,minval,temp;
 int n,i,j,j1,k;
 int gd=DETECT,gm;
 char x1[10],y1[10];
 clrscr();
     
       initgraph(&gd,&gm,"d:\\tc\\");

       setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL,YELLOW);
            pieslice(100,100,135,-135,20);
       pieslice(200,200,225,135,30);
 pieslice(300,300,225,360+135,30);

 pieslice(400,400,60,-240,20);

 getche();
}

Comment: @Timothy: It is customary to update the question with new information. Code added to comments is hard to read. See Robin's answer for a solution.

Comment: @dave : even robin's solution is not working :(

Answer (score 2):

Draw two pie slices with the same centre and radius, one from 0 to 135 degrees, and one from 225 to 0 degrees. It seems that the function is forcing the pie slices to be always less than 180 degrees, so this should work around that.

See also: http://electrosofts.com/cgraphics/

Comment: @Robin: Saved me from installing Turbo C. ;-)

Comment: @ Robin and Dave : thanks a lot, i have tried that too, but even that does not solve the problem , i am getting a sector, but its not like that which starts at 135 and ends at 225,, its something different,, please look into it

Comment: @Timothy: Provide some screen captures. Use http://imgur.com/. Post the links, don't try to inline the images; someone else will inline them for you. Edit to update your question.

Comment: @dave :i have uploaded the screenshot of the output, the one slice that you see in the top most left corner is the one suggested by robin,  http://postimage.org/image/1wytkbdic/

Comment: Are you sure you didn't enter 90 degrees by mistake instead of 135 degrees for the top-left one?

Comment: @robin no robin i am sure i did this
  pieslice(50,50,0,135,30); pieslice(50,50,225,0,30);

Answer (score 0):

here is my game loop using pieslice . pacman moves to and fro.

```
for (int dx = 10, dy = 0, dt = 100; c != 'q';) {
    if ((x + rx + dx) > getmaxx() || (x + rx + dx) < 0) {
    dx = -dx;
    rx = -rx;
    }
    if ((y + ry + dy) > getmaxy() || (y + ry + dy) < 0) {
    dy = -dy;
    ry = -ry;
    }
    delay(dt);
    cleardevice();
    //gotoxy(1,1);
    //cout << x+rx << " " << y+ry << " " << m;
    pieslice(x, y, (sa + m), (ea - m), RADIUS);
    //floodfill(x,y,getcolor());

    if (m + dm < 0 || m + dm > ea)
     dm = -dm;

    m += dm;

    x += dx;
    y += dy;
    if (kbhit())
     c = getch();
}
```